# nestjs MongoDB uniqie field not working on function

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

Need help about make a uniqe:true for my name prop in nestjs - mongodb schema,but its not working as a default like that

```
@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop()
  userId:string;
  
  @Prop({ 
    type:String,
    required:true,
  })
  name:string;

  @Prop({ required: true})
  password:string;
  
  @Prop({ required: true })
  email:string;

  @Prop({default:"user"})
  role:string
}
```

this is works on required or default but not work on uniqe field

Answer (score 0):

Just add the unique property to the name `@Props` like this:

```
@Prop({ 
    type:String,
    required:true,
    unique: true
})
name: string;
```

Comment: tried,not working

Comment: @MustafaKendigüzel  Drop User collection from mongo and make sure that the index exists in the collection

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean to validate the field, using IsUnique, something like:

```
import { Schema, Prop } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { IsUnique } from 'class-validator';


@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop()
  userId:string;
  
  @Prop({ 
    type:String,
    required:true,
  })
  name:string;

  @Prop({ required: true})
  password:string;
  
  @Prop({ required: true })
  @IsUnique({ message: 'The field must be unique.' })
  email:string;

  @Prop({default:"user"})
  role:string
}
```